# Flask Error sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: role "admin" does not exist

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I cant make out what am doing wrong on flask webapp. I think it has to do with the database. I have postgres as the database below is the:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

db = SQLAlchemy()
# db.init_app(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    passwdhash = db.Column(db.String(54))

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, email, password):
        self.firstname = firstname.title()
        self.lastname = lastname.title()
        self.email = email.lower()
        self.set_password(password)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.passwdhash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password_hash(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.passwdhash, password)
```

Then I get this error... 
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  role "pipi" does not exist
 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: I realized that I have no role in the database named "pipi" after I created it and gave it permission the program proceeded as expected.